# Can't mount terabyte drive

Tags: mount

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer, but for some reason I can't mount my Kingston SNV425S264GB drive. It was there when I had Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  and now its not. What can I do to get it back? I tried using mount manager but that didn't work. I tried using recovery and that didn't work. Did I do something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try using "disk utility" from GUI see if it shows up there. in terminal try mounting with sudo 
example: sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt.
could look for it in the fstab  enter  less /etc/fstab

if its a usb the command lsusb may show its mount point and or that the system recognises the fs

the disk utility program has helped me a few times mount usb drives my system wouldn't auto mount